# How to check if two fields have same value using msql?

Tags: php, mysql

i am having problem using mysql statement in which i want to check whether fan followed and fan following is having same value as user and username, here is my code :

```
<?
$selectfan = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM amityfans");
$fanrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($selectfan);
$fan_following = $fanrow['fan_following'];
$fan_followed = $fanrow['fan_followed'];
if ($fan_following == "$user" && $fan_followed=="$username") {
 $addasfan = '<input type="submit" class="button" name="removefriend" value="Remove fan">';
}
else
{
 $addasfan = '<input type="submit" class="button" name="addfriend" value="Add Me as Fan">';
}
echo $addasfan;
?>
```

But even if 'user' and 'username' have same values then it is not displaying remove fan button. FYI $user is username of logged in user and $username is username of profile we are seeing.

EDIT :

I am also having problem in deleting the particular row of fan having user and username here is my code :

```
<?php
//$user = logged in user
//$username = user who owns profile
if (isset($_POST['removefriend'])) {
$removefan = mysql_query("DELETE FROM amityusers WHERE fan_following='$user' && fan_followed='$username'");
}
?>
```

Comment: why double quotes for "$user" and "$username"?

Comment: Why don't you check this in MySQL? `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM amityfans WHERE fan_following = '$user' AND fan_followed = '$username';`

Comment: try to echo our `$fan_following, $fan_followed, $user, and $username` to see what values are being assigned to those variables and then look for exact matches manually.

Comment: Change `if ($fan_following == $user && $fan_followed == $username)` to `if($fan_following == $fan_followed)` which worked for me upon testing (*to a certain extent*).

Comment: Definitely there is a problem with IF statement, but its hard to say what exactly if we don't know what is in field `fan_following` and `fan_followed`.

Comment: Change your second SQL query to - "DELETE FROM amityusers WHERE fan_following='$user' AND fan_followed='$username'"

Comment: `&&` and `AND` both perform the same action and are both valid. @danielsmile The question has been answered and accepted, where both issues have been answered at the same time. OP is obviously using relational tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having **FRED** in the `fan_following` column and **BOB** in `fan_followed` produced the `Add Me as Fan` button.

Having **BOB** in the `fan_following` column and **BOB** in `fan_followed` produced the `Remove fan` button.

by changing:

```
if ($fan_following == "$user" && $fan_followed=="$username")
```

to:

```
if ($fan_following == $fan_followed)
```

**^--«** (Which I believe should also take care of your deletion problem, that I also tested successfully using your code inside a function I setup inside the same script.

this I have done by setting up a quick DB.

using the following:

```
<?php

$DB_HOST = "xxx";
$DB_NAME = "xxx";
$DB_PASS = "xxx";
$DB_USER = "xxx";


$db = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME);
if($db->connect_errno > 0) {
  die('Connection failed [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

$user = "FRED";
$username = "BOB";

 $selectfan = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM amityfans");

$fanrow = mysqli_fetch_assoc($selectfan);
$fan_following = $fanrow['fan_following'];
$fan_followed = $fanrow['fan_followed'];

 if ($fan_following == $fan_followed) {

 $addasfan = '<input type="submit" class="button" name="removefriend" value="Remove fan">';

}
else
{
 $addasfan = '<input type="submit" class="button" name="addfriend" value="Add Me as Fan">';
}
echo $addasfan;
?>
```